# echarts4r pie chart highlight colour

Tags: r, dplyr, echarts4r

I have a dataset in a similar format to the below. I would like to highlight the "blue_wedge" class in one colour (e.g., blue) and for all other wedges (in this example "2nd" and "3rd" classes) to share a second colour (e.g., "grey") -- helping me better highlight the proportion of "deaths" for whatever the "blue_wedge" value happens to be.

```
Titanic <- as.data.frame(Titanic)

blue_wedge <- "1st"

Titanic %>% 
  filter(Class %in% c('1st','2nd','3rd')) %>% 
  group_by(Class) %>% 
  summarise(People = sum(Freq)) %>% 
  e_charts(Class) %>%  
  e_pie(People, radius = c("50%", "70%"), legend = FALSE)
```

I have tried looking at other similar questions (e.g., [How to set fixed colors for each value in echarts4r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69838735/how-to-set-fixed-colors-for-each-value-in-echarts4r)), but haven't had any success so far. Any help really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option to create a vector of colors which could then be used in `e_color` to achieve your desired result:

```
library(echarts4r)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

cols <- rep("grey", nlevels(factor(Titanic$Class)))
cols[levels(factor(Titanic$Class)) == blue_wedge] <- "blue"

Titanic %>%
  filter(Class %in% c("1st", "2nd", "3rd")) %>%
  group_by(Class) %>%
  summarise(People = sum(Freq)) %>%
  e_charts(Class) %>%
  e_pie(People, radius = c("50%", "70%"), legend = FALSE) %>%
  e_color(color = cols)
```

[image]